# Request multiple pages on some site useing one connection with python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, keep-alive

I want to parse multiple (about 180) pages from one site. 
In python i'm doing like this:

```
def myFunc(pages):
forreturn=[]
session=requests.session()
for page in pages:    #List, containing page addresses
    url = 'http://example.com/' + page 
    # we get something like 'http://example.com/sub1/page.html'
    # Ant the part with "sub1" is different each time.
    answer = session.get(url)
    soup=Soup(answer.text)
    # There we parse needed string and append it to "forreturn" list
return forreturn
```

As I understood, when doing like this, i'm opening a new connection to server when new page is requested.
So is there a way to get all this pages useing only one connection?

(it might improve getting responce time and server stress would be lower, as i think)

Comment: Fix indentation please.

Comment: According to the docs you get it "for free" when using requests.Session: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Under HTTP 1.0, you can do it more explicitly.

   session.get(url, headers={'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'})
2. In HTTP 1.1, all connections are considered persistent unless declared otherwise.
3. As @FlorianLudwig has mentioned with http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive that "keep-alive is 100% automatic within a session"